# How to parse full data escaping &amp; in java sax parser

Tags: java, parsing, sax

Please help me with this:
I am parsing some xml files using sax parser in java. However when the parser detects & it does not parse the current line further and moves to parsing next element.

I have tried StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(String) but it didnt work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does "detects &" mean?

Comment: Please show a [mcve] - the question is too unclear to answer at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

SAXParser splits a text element to one or more separate chunks when encountering `&amp;` or maybe few other delimiters as well.

This is how I do it, read current element name in a startElement callback, store it somewhere, concatenate chunks.

```
@Override public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
    super.characters(ch, start, length);
    String value = new String(ch, start, length);
    String oldval = cachedProps.get(elemName);
    if (oldval!=null) value = oldval+value;
    cachedProps.put(elemName, value);
}
```

You may want to study [StAXParser](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/stax/why.html) to read XML files as a stream. It is usually better suited and controllable by own applications. SAX callback interface is sometimes a tough case.

- DOM=everything read into RAM on opening a file
- SAX=streaming, "push" callback mode
- StAX=streaming, "pull" mode